# Bash: how to do string replacements in function?

Tags: bash, function, parameters, return

I wrote a bash script with a curl statement and many sed statements after that. I would like to move all the sed replacements in a fucntion so that the curl statement looks better. How can I pass a parameter? Should I store the result of curl in a variable? And how does return in function work?

```
function do_replacements () {

}

curl -s http.... | do_replacements > target.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could ignore stderr to prevent printing of the transfer summary and read from stdin in the function:

```
do_replacements() {
  sed 's/foo/bar/g;s/abc/def/g'
}

curl http://… 2>/dev/null | do_replacements > target.txt
```

There is no "return" value as such, the function prints the modified result to stdout and this output is then redirected to `target.txt`.

Comment: No reason to run `sed` twice here. You had put both substitutions in the same invocations, separated by semicolons in GNU `sed`, or newlines in general. You also don't have to actively redirect from stdin - that's standard.

Comment: @PaulHodges Thanks for your feedback! I added your suggestions to the answer.

Comment: Good edit after the feedback. You can also delete the keyword `function`.

Comment: @WalterA Also done for [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_05) portability.

Comment: Whether you redirect standard error or not has no affect on what `do_replacements` sees on its input or writes to `target.txt`.